# Compare postgres db indexes between two databases

Tags: postgresql

I've used red-gate's sql compare with sqlserver for checking table/index/proc differences, is there anything similar for postgres?

What I want to do is figure out between development, QA, and production databases if there are any indexes or other schema changes in case something was missed.

Comment: Check out [dbForge Data Compare for PostgreSQL](https://www.devart.com/dbforge/postgresql/datacompare/). 30-day trial is  available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one implementation that will do what you are looking for: http://sqlmanager.net/en/products/postgresql/dbcomparer

Answer (score 0):

Check_postgres from bucardo has a schema diff option.  http://bucardo.org/check_postgres/check_postgres.pl.html#same_schema  This a perl-based script I have used and found handy.